# how to fix the width of a td or table so that it does not stretches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a table dynamically, and including some preformatted text from an xml file into it, but my table stretches to fit the whole content, instead i want to have table size fixed, a horizontal scroll can also work, please provide some solution.

Here is my  code

```
$('#detailTable').empty();
$('<div width="100%">')
.attr('id','dblistSpan')
.html('<div class="titleBlue">Configuration&gt;System&gt;DBList</div>'+
        '<table id="grid" style="border:#2F5882 1px solid;width:100%;overflow:hidden;"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">'+
            '<tr style="color :#FFFFFF;background-color: #8EA4BB">'+
                '<th><b>DBlist'+
                '</b></th>'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<tr style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #EDF1F5;width:100%;overflow:hidden;">'+
                '<td style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;"><pre>'+dblist+
                '</pre></td>'+
            '<tr>'+
        '</table>'+                 
    '</div>')       
.appendTo('#detailTable');
```

Comment: Simply give it fixed width e.g. `width: 500px; overflow: scroll;`

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: how about if the resolution increases, will it maintain?

Comment: No, that's the downside of fixed width.. but you can use JavaScript in such case and apply fixed width once according to the screen resolution. Code is pretty simple let me know if you want.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Can you please provide me the code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the contents fixed width, you'll have to assign fixed width to the `<pre>` tag itself:

```
<pre style="width: 500px; overflow:scroll;">'+dblist+....
```

To make it relative to screen resolution, first calculate the desired width e.g. 1/5 of the screen width:

```
var listWidth = parseInt(screen.width / 5, 10);
```

Then use this in the code:

```
<pre style="width:' + listWidth + 'px; overflow:scroll;">'+dblist+....
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/C2GGf/

Comment: I'll check it and get back to you tomorrow morning 1st thing in my office :) Thanks

Comment: I only want a horizontal scroll, the content should show as it is vertically. Also what is `10` in `parseInt(screen.width / 5, 10)`

Comment: @Abhishek try having `overflow-x: scroll;` as for the `10` it's the base - it means parse the integer as ordinary number - `parseInt(screen.width / 5, 16)` will give the number in hex format for example (base 16)

Comment: Thanks i figured it out too :)